# Why does a typo in a Haskell function declaration cause GHCi to throw errors around previously compiling code?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Here's sort of a weird question. Learning Haskell through LearnYouaHaskell, great book btw, and I'm going through implementing various examples.

**This compiles in GHCi**

```
cylinder :: (RealFloat a) => a -> a -> a
cylinder r h =
    let sideArea = 2 * pi * r * h
    topArea = pi * r ^2
    in  sideArea + 2 * topArea
```

**This compiles in GHCi**

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]  
zipWith' _ [] _ = []  
zipWith' _ _ [] = []  
zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f x y : zipWith' f xs ys
```

**If I intentionally make a typo and declare the second function as so**

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]  
zipWith' _ [] _ = []  
zipWith' _ _ [] = []  
zipWith' f (x:xs) (y:ys) = f xs y : zipWith' f xs ys
```

**Then the first and second function throw errors during compilation** - at least that's what I think is happening.

Sorry in advance for the code dump.

**It throws this previously unseen error message about the cylinder function which I did not change**

```
Prelude> :l functions2.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( functions2.hs, interpreted )

functions2.hs:4:26:
    Could not deduce (Integral b0) arising from a use of ‘^’
    from the context (RealFloat a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 cylinder :: RealFloat a => a -> a -> a
      at functions2.hs:1:13-40
    The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Integral Int -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      instance Integral GHC.Types.Word -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
    In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘r ^ 2’
    In the expression: pi * r ^ 2
    In an equation for ‘topArea’: topArea = pi * r ^ 2

functions2.hs:4:27:
    Could not deduce (Num b0) arising from the literal ‘2’
    from the context (RealFloat a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 cylinder :: RealFloat a => a -> a -> a
      at functions2.hs:1:13-40
    The type variable ‘b0’ is ambiguous
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Real’
      ...plus three others
    In the second argument of ‘(^)’, namely ‘2’
    In the second argument of ‘(*)’, namely ‘r ^ 2’
    In the expression: pi * r ^ 2
```

**As well as this much more reasonable error message about the typo in the second function**

```
functions2.hs:12:30:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘[a]’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
          at functions2.hs:9:13
    Relevant bindings include
      xs :: [a] (bound at functions2.hs:12:15)
      x :: a (bound at functions2.hs:12:13)
      f :: a -> b -> c (bound at functions2.hs:12:10)
      zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
        (bound at functions2.hs:10:1)
    In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘xs’
    In the first argument of ‘(:)’, namely ‘f xs y’
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Why? Is this a common bug? Did I break something in the first by ruining the second? Please advise.

Comment: I've seen similar problems. A type error in one function makes ghc "confused" about another function.  I think it's because it stops applying defaulting after a type error.  This problem has just gotten worse in newer versions of ghc and is very annoying since the real error is often not the first reported error.  It's really a ghc bug.

Comment: Right, this is a GHC bug and it's pretty annoying. However, note that `^` in particular is a bit of a problem child: its signature completely decouples the exponent and basis/result-types, making a polymorphic argument such as numerical literals ambiguous. I have therefore made it a habit to locally constrict `(^) :: Num a => a -> Int -> a`. With that done, you can actually get quite far without feeling the need for defaulting at all, because most functions couple the argument- and result types in some rigid way that allows unambiguous inference of all local types from the top-level signature.

Comment: I found GHC 7.10 to be better at this than GHC 7.8. Which version are you using?

Comment: Ok, I just tested with `ghc-7.10.1` and it just shows a single error (the more reasonable second one). So, I guess things are better now than they were before.

Comment: This was [GHC bug ticket #9033](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9033), fixed in April 2014.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen That could be expanded in a short answer.

Comment: @chi OK, I tried to collect together the main points mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was [GHC bug ticket #9033](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/9033), reported in April 2014 and quickly fixed.

Basically, whenever a file contained almost *any* type error, GHC would skip the type class defaulting step, which could cause other parts of the file to give spurious ambiguous type errors.

As @leftaroundabout notes, the `^` operator is a frequent trigger of this, since its second argument type is unconnected with the other types and so very often needs defaulting.

The GHC version listed in the ticket is 7.8.2, and 7.8.3 was released in July 2104, so I assume versions 7.8.3 and later have the fix.

Comment: Thanks, it looked like a bug but as a relatively new programmer I never like to be the boy who cried defect.